# Adobe Flash Player Does Not Load on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, flash

I am having a problem with Adobe Flash Player with Internet Explorer 11. The problem is that whenever I visit a website that has content that needs the flash player in order to work, Internet Explorer asks me if it is okay to run the content. When I click "Allow", the page refreshes and I am asked again. I do not understand why it behaves this way because I have all Adobe plugins for Internet Explorer activated.

To see the problem that I am having in action, [watch this video](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByUR3cLNvdDpTFF6aE9ybU1Ocmc/edit?pli=1).

Comment: If you click the arrow righ-next to `Allow` and choose `Always allow` what happens?

Comment: @Cornelius The page reloads and I am asked again and again and again. Did you watch the video? It shows what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue with a client a bit ago. It must be something with that update. The only resolution I found was to uninstall flash and reinstall it. If you have issues uninstalling flash use this page for help http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/uninstall-flash-player-windows.html

Comment: I uninstalled Flash and then reinstalled it and that did not work. I use Turn Windows Features on or Off to uninstall and reinstall Internet Explorer 11 and that did not work. What next? I am running out of ideas.

Comment: Use the adobe removal tool. It should get rid of everything. I would suggest to not use IE 11 but thats not much of a solution.

Comment: If you are referring to the uninstall tool available at the link you gave me, I have already tried it. Regarding your suggestion to not use IE 11, I already use it very rarely. The only reason that I am worried about it is because I need to access a web app that only works in IE and requires Flash at the same time.